# Como usar contentType Ajax para transferir dados XML e JSON entre serviços?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, route, http-headers

Boa tarde pessoal!
Preciso passar dados nos formatos XML e JSON para uma API que estou desenvolvendo.
Toda vez que coloco o contentType: "application/json/xml; charset=utf-8" no meu bloco Ajax, obtenho o seguinte erro

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.meuservico.com.br/api. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

> ```
>     $(function() {
>         $.ajax({
>             type: "post",
>             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
>             url: 'http://www.e-sms.com.br/api',
>             data: { name: 'norm' },
>             dataType: "json",
>             success: function(data){
>                 console.log(data);
>             },
>             error: function (request) {
>                 console.log(request);
>             }
>         });        
>     });
> ```

No servidor, eu tenho os seguintes Header definidos:

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type, Accept"); header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT');

Comment: Esse erro só acontece quando define o content type?

Comment: Sim, se eu remover, tudo funciona.

Comment: Acredito que tenha mais uma informação relevante;

Comment: O DataType funciona cirretanebte.

Comment: Depois de uma pesquisa dê uma olhadela aqui: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ , veja a parte do content type. E depois vi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685678/cors-how-do-preflight-an-httprequest e aqui http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320467/jquery-cors-content-type-options