# Como utilizar o contentType enviado pelo cliente, no servidor

Tags: php, jquery, json, xml, http-headers

Boa tarde! Estou tentando entender o funcinamento do contentType.
Até onde eu sei, eu estaria dizendo ao servidor para usar o formado JSON UTF8 para codificar corretamente os dados que estou enviado. `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` Se estiver correto, ainda me falta saber como utilizar essa informação. Até agora eu imaginava que seria incluindo os header.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Type: text/json; charset=utf-8');
```

Nesse caso, se estiver correto, existe algum outro problema, porque não consigo fazer funcionar.

```
Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Comment: Qual é a diferênça entre esta pergunta [e a outra?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/139381/129)

Comment: Se você responder a essa pergunta, você irá ver a diferença.
Você concordou com as minhas afirmações eu acredito, pois você desviou o foco do tópico, correto ?

Comment: Willian não percebi o que queres dizer com _"você desviou o foco do tópico"_. A ideia da minha pergunta era tentar que essas perguntas sejam o mais específicas possível para serem de facto perguntas diferentes. Ao mesmo tempo que não tenho a certeza se percebes o que CORS é e o que quer dizer esse erro que estás a receber.

Comment: Desculpe. O que quero saber é sobre o funcionamento do ContentType.
Acredito que ele seja uma orientação para o servidor saber como interpretar os dados que está recebendo.
Desculpe, não sei o que é CORS.

Comment: Este é um problema que estou enfrentando e não estou conseguindo resolver. Estou acreditando segamente que o Content-Type é a minha solução.
A minha API pode receber tanto XML quanto JSON.

Comment: Só não sei como identificar um ou outro.